# How would you play a sound every certain amount of seconds in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

I need to play a sound using Phaser Framework that plays every 10 seconds. But how can I implement a event that gets executed when the sound finished playing ? so then I can start a 10 second timer to play the sound again.

Comment: Do you want to play the sound effect (which takes x seconds) and then wait 10 seconds, or do you want to play the sound every 10 seconds? Depending on which, you can either use the Sound.onStop event or a Time object.

Comment: I ended up using the onStop event and inside that, I created a timer that plays the sound again, after 10 seconds. I didn't know the onStop event was called when the sound finished playing, I was always looking for a onComplete, but that doesn't exists for sounds. Also I had to onStop.removeAll() later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event on the sound. E.g:

```
sound.onStop.add( // When it ends set a timeout function to restart it
    function() {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                sound.play();
            },
            10000 // Delay
        )
    }
);
sound.play();
```

You might be able to simplify this code by using Phaser tweens, but I haven't used them much so I don't really know how.